# Is there a macro for creating tables with repeated columns in MySQL WorkBench?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, mysql-workbench, workbench

I find myself building many tables in MySQL Workbench that have the same first three columns:

1. id
2. isActive
3. lastChanged

Not only are these three columns repeated, but their exact properties (not null, auto increment for the id, default value of 1 for isActive, etc) are also repeated.

So my Question:

-Does there exist a macro to begin building the table for a given table name, to speed up this process?

-If not can someone provide a link to getting me started for building something like this?

(Then after using this macro I can fill in the additional columns but the database development time will be less).

Thanks!

Comment: A little context would help to understand why you have practically identical tables? 3NF revision might not go amiss

Comment: @Ed - isActive is used rather than sql delete statements, id is used as a unique identifier, lastChanged is used to show creation of rows, and date of rows change. The tables are not at all identical, simply I would like to continue repeating the first few columns. I hope that helps clear up the reason I am looking for a macro?

Comment: Just create a text file of SQL statements and use copy 'n' paste to duplicate the bits that are required. Anyway what is the problem with the `DELETE` SQL statement?

Comment: @Ed wow copy paste of text, thats actually a fantastic idea, and im rather embarassed I didnt think of that. I guess i got caught up using the GUI.. As for the delete - it is often better to mark as inactive, and then update a lastChanged date. If the data doesnt need to be un-deleted for a certain period of time, then it can be purged via scheduled script. That helps with my business cases, though I do understand its not for everyones! Anyways thanks again.

Comment: I do not know what business logic that you are trying to implement. Also if you have a script you can use it for both a development and release system (perhaps one for testing?!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question - which I thought of based on a great suggestion by Ed Heal (see his comments above), would be to use the SQL Additions to workbench - Snippets.

You can add a new snippet under 'My Snippets' which contains the create table script, rather than maintaining in a text file, and then just fill in the rest of the columns after you do a right mouse + 'insert snippet at text cursor'